# Issue on Data-Driven Documents (D3) click event

Tags: angular, d3.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using [**D3: Data-Driven Documents**](https://github.com/d3/d3) Js library.I have plotted a bar chart as shown below.It is working fine.Now I have a requirement to send `this.data` array back to the parent component through `events publish`.But the problem here is when I clicked the bar chart item, the value of `this.data` is `undefined`.Which is correct.But can you tell me how to send the particular array (`this.data`) back to the parent component when the user `clicks` the bar chart item?

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            var item = this.data[i];
            this.svg.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "interval")
                .attr("y", offset + item['start'] * max_height / 86400)
                .attr("x", horz_inset)
                .attr("height", item['length'] * max_height / 86400)
                .attr("width", width - 2 * horz_inset)
                .on("click", function () {
                   this.events.publish('intervals', this.data);
                });
        }
```

Comment: Did you try arrow function to retain context?

Comment: Yes, it is working.Please put it as an answer.Thank you so much :) @yurzui