# Data-Driven Documents (D3.js) change color when clicked

Tags: angular, d3.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using [**Data-Driven Documents (D3.js)**](https://d3js.org/) library to plot a bar chart.It is working fine.Now I need to change the color of the bar chart when the user clicks it.But it is not working.Can you tell me why?

**Note:** When I use `D3.selectAll(".interval").style("fill", "#F96845");` then it changes the color of all the bar charts.But I need to change only the color of clicked one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
        var item = this.data[i];
        this.svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "interval")
            .attr("y", offset + item['start'] * max_height / 86400)
            .attr("x", horz_inset)
            .attr("height", item['length'] * max_height / 86400)
            .attr("width", width - 2 * horz_inset)
            .on("click", () => {
              D3.select(".interval").style("fill", "#F96845");//here it is not working?
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any seasoned D3 coder would simply say: *"drop the arrow function and use `this` with a regular function"*, which is a correct advise. However, this question should link your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43548355/5768908), making clear that you have a reason to use an arrow function.

Thus, your real problem is: how to get `this` referring to the DOM element in an arrow function?

The solution is: use a combination of the second and third arguments to get `this` DOM element inside an arrow function:

```
.on("click", (d, i, n) => {
    d3.select(n[i]).style("fill", "#F96845");
});
```

To read more about getting `this` DOM element in an arrow function, have a look at this example: [d3 v4 retrieve drag DOM target from drag callback when `this` is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262172/d3-v4-retrieve-drag-dom-target-from-drag-callback-when-this-is-not-available/45262284#45262284)

EDIT: If you want to change the style of the clicked element and revert the style of the previously clicked element, you can simply apply a style to all elements using `selectAll` before applying the style in the clicked one, or, alternatively, you can apply the style to all elements, including the clicked one, at once:

```js
var circles = d3.select("svg").selectAll("foo")
  .data(d3.range(10))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .style("fill", "firebrick")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", d => 20 + d * 30)
  .attr("r", 10);

circles.on("click", (d, i, n) => {
  circles.style("fill", (e, j) => n[i] === n[j] ? "lime" : "firebrick")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: @Sampath I saw your previous comment, before you deleted it. Check the edit regarding how to do what you asked.

Comment: Hehe... :D Thank you so much for your invaluable feedback. For that use case I just do this hack `D3.selectAll(".interval").style("fill", "#10BDD7");//remove highlight` before the `D3.select(n[i]).style("fill", "#F96845");//add highlight`.